# GitHub Import: Could not locate Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, git-clone, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I have imported a Rails Application from "GitHub",  https://github.com/farra/goo.git

While trying to do `bundle install` in that it shows "Could not locate Gemfile".

That repository actually don't have the below listed files with it.

> Gemfile, Gemfile.lock & config.ru

I would like some assistance to proceed with that application.

Is there any way to create a Gemfile for that application with its necessary Gems?

Thank You In Advance...

Comment: I don't see a Gemfile in that repository. Although, did you follow the instructions [posted here](https://github.com/farra/goo#install-and-run)?

Comment: I don't think you need to create a Gemfile. Did you got time to look at config/environment.rb file? This application is using Rails 2.3.4. Install rails 2.3.4 gem and try doing `rake gems:install`

Comment: Hi, the application have old ruby and rails versions inside it, so you have to install according to application configuration. And one more the bundler is a new thing, which is started from rails3 and above versions, check the rails2 commands, It will defiantly work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very legacy codebase and bundler is not initialized. So in order to install its gem files you need to run the following command:

```
rake gems:install
```

checkout their environment file:
[config/environment.rb](https://github.com/farra/goo/blob/master/config/environment.rb)

And they have defined some possible steps to run that project I think you should read them carefully. For your reference, I am sharing here again:

```
rails goo
cd goo
script/plugin install git://github.com/dcu/nanite-rails.git
./script/generate nanite
./script/generate agent counter schedule count
./script/generate model Count total:integer interval:integer
./script/generate controller counts
rake db:migrate
modify environment.rb
modify routes.rb
setup passenger vhosts # for production server
edit the counts_counter and the count nanite agent
```

I hope my answer could give you enough info now to move forward. Thanks